# Custom UIButton focus not working properly in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, tvos

I have a `UIViewController` like this

```
  +View
       button1
       button2
       backgroundImage
       ScrollView
              scrollBackgroundImage
              scrollButton1
              scrollButton2
```

All the buttons are of **custom type** 
if initial focus is on `button1` then no matter what I do focus never goes to buttons that are inside `scrollView`.
If initial focus is on `button2` then focus never goes to `button1`/`button2`.

If I change all buttons to type **System** then focus starts working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, focus does go between `button1` and `button2`.

If you change button type to `Custom`, it means that you should handle visual focus updates yourself ( for example, in `didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)` method ).